# Show hidden files IN SELECT folders only

Tags: hidden-files

How do I show hidden files in one directory only? I have a development folder that I'd like to see hidden files in, but I don't want to see hidden files anywhere else on my computer.

Here is the code I tried in the terminal to show **all** hidden files but it's not what I want. Thanks!

```
    defaults write com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles TRUE
    killall Finder
```

Comment: Do you want them to be visible temporarily? If so, try `ls -a`. Hopefully I didn't misinterpret your question.

Comment: Dylan, good question. I know the "ls -a" command but I want them to be visible permanently.

Comment: This question is better suited for apple.stackexchange.com.